# How to change/convert input date format from MM dd yy to yyyy-mm-dd on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to figure out how to change a dateFormat MM dd yy to yyyy-mm-dd on a form submit. In my example https://codepen.io/monsmado/pen/ExxodEY I have put the output on a alert to see what happens but I cannot find any solution on changing MM to mm.

```
<input type="text" id="fromdate" class="datepicker form-control dpd1" 
name="from" placeholder="Select From Date"> <span class="input-group- 
addon"></span>
<input type="button" class="getdate" value="Change Date">
```

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'MM dd yy'
})

$('.getdate').on('click', function() {
    var date = $('#fromdate').val().split(" ");
    day = date[1];
    month = date[0];
    year = date[2];
    alert([year, month, day].join('-'));
});
```

Comment: Why not just change the datepicker format to the one you need?

Comment: I want do display MM dd yy, as it looks nicer (user friendly) and then convert it to yyyy-mm-dd on submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Edit dateFormat

When **initializing** your datepicker, you can specify a **defined format**.

You can try the following :

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
})
```

### $.datepicker.formatDate function

If you need a specific format for you datepicker, you can also user `formatDate` function from [datepicker documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) with any `date object`:

```
// Display the date in ISO format. Produces "2007-01-26".
$.datepicker.formatDate( "yy-mm-dd", new Date( 2007, 1 - 1, 26 ) );
```

Using your code:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'MM dd yy'
});
$('.getdate').on('click', function() {
    var date = $( "#fromdate" ).datepicker( "getDate" );
    var date_str = $.datepicker.formatDate( "yy-mm-dd", date );
});
```

Comment: The thing is that I want to keep MM dd yy format when selecting a date in the input field. And then onClick convert the date format to yy-mm-dd.
Perhaps I should use a hidden field where the date format gets converted/changed to yy-mm-dd format when submit

Comment: Or as I mentionned in my answer use `$.datepicker.formatDate function`